# Update H2O Cluster on AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, h2o

Hi I have installed H2O for python on my AWS VM (Amazon Linux), python 3.5 by following the instructions here: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-ueno/8/index.html

But when I initialize h2o I am getting an error that I have version mismatch as h2o is running clusters on 3.10.4.8.

I can run this in aws terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip h2o-3.15.0.4049.zip
cd h2o-3.15.0.4049
java -jar h2o.jar
```

to get the latest h2o clusters, but I still get the same mismatch error.

I could use an older version of the python h2o, but that wont work for me as I need the newer features in the latest release of h2o.

Comment: Is the older version working for you with H20 ?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine until I upgraded the python h2o. I now need to successfully upgrade the h2o cluster

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.

I was under the false impression that you had to download the cluster and the python package separately. In fact its much easier just to let the python package start the cluster.

All I had to do was uninstall everything, and simply use pip to install the latest h2o.

Similar to this answer here but in reverse:

[OSError: Version mismatch while installing h2o?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779076/oserror-version-mismatch-while-installing-h2o)