# Version mismatch. H2O is version 3.22.0.1, but the h2o-python package is version 0.0.local

Tags: h2o

I am following the H2O install manual. I can run the jar and get web access, but every time I install python packages via the instruction on the website I am getting the issue:

Version mismatch. H2O is version 3.22.0.1, but the h2o-python package is version 0.0.local

When running the h2o.init()

I am installing the h2o python on macOS using python 3.6 inside a fresh virtual environment I created.

Any Ideas

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while trying to initiate h2o inside a virtual environment using jupyter notebook.

As it has been said on the previous thread [OSError: Version mismatch while installing h2o?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779076/oserror-version-mismatch-while-installing-h2o) you probably have to kill the h2o cluster. In my case it worked with:

`h2o.cluster().shutdown()`

Answer (score 0):

this question is a duplicate of this questions: [OSError: Version mismatch while installing h2o?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779076/oserror-version-mismatch-while-installing-h2o)

basically you need to make sure your h2o.jar version matches the version you ahve for you python package. You can also find more of a walk through.

for the python package you might just need to uninstall the version you currently have with a pip uninstall and then reinstall the latest wheel file found on the H2O-3 downloads page: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xia/1/index.html and click on the python tab.